# Can I assign multiple data entries to one variable & if so how?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm using Linux Bash/Shell and i would like to know how to assign multiple separate data entries to one variable.

For e.g. list of teams.
each team needs data of: total goals scored at home - total goals scored away - total goals conceded at home - total goals conceded away etc.

Comment: If you are willing to use the `ksh93` version of the Korn shell, you can easily do what you are looking to do using `compound` variables.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` shell can store single strings in single ordinary variables, lists of strings in arrays, and strings associated with other strings in associative arrays.  You would not be able to store e.g. arrays of arrays or associative arrays of associative arrays (or combinations thereof).

For the particular data that you mention, you *could* do something like an associative array:

```
declare -A goals

goals["teamA"]="0:2:3:4"
goals["teamB"]="1:3:3:3"
# etc.
```

or

```
declare -A goals

goals=(
    ["teamA"]="0:2:3:4"
    ["teamB"]="1:3:3:3"
    # etc.
)
```

and then parse out the `:`-delimited values when you need them:

```
for team in "${!goals[@]}"; do
    home_goals=$( cut -d : -f1 <<<"${goals[$team]}" )
    away_goals=$( cut -d : -f2 <<<"${goals[$team]}" )
    # etc.

    # use "$team", "$home_goals", "$away_goals" etc. here
done
```

... but it would be *much* more efficient to do this in a language such as Perl or Python that *does* allow for arbitrarily nested data structures.

E.g., in Perl:

```
my %goals = ( "teamA" => [ 0, 2, 3, 4 ],
              "teamB" => [ 1, 3, 3, 3 ],
              # etc.
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

The shells I know don't really deal well with structural data like that, since they don't have any nested data structures. (That includes Bash, which you tagged.) You'd want a list of objects or C-style structs, but all you can have are arrays and associative arrays.

One way to do that would be to make separate associative arrays for each piece of data you have (goals scored, goals conceded...), and key the arrays by the team names.

So, e.g.

```
declare -A goals_scored goals_conceded
goals_scored[Liverpool]=4
goals_conceded[Liverpool]=2
goals_scored[Tottenham]=3
goals_conceded[Tottenham]=3
for team in "${!goals_scored[@]}"; do       # iterate over the keys of goals_scored
    echo "$team has scored ${goals_scored[$team]} goals"
done
```

That's somewhat ugly since the data items are on the top level, and if you also had structures for e.g. players, they would start getting mixed up. (For example, `goals_scored` could apply to a team or a player, so you'd have to separate them somehow.)

It would probably be a better idea to use a proper programming language.

See [Arrays/Associative Arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays-1) on [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for more on associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in `ksh93` with compound variables:

```
ksh93$ typeset -A teams
ksh93$ teams[A]=(scored=(home=3 away=7) conceded=(home=1 away=0))
ksh93$ teams[B]=(scored=(home=2 away=0) conceded=(home=3 away=1))

ksh93$ echo ${teams[A].conceded}
( away=0 home=1 )
ksh93$ echo ${teams[A].conceded.away}
0
ksh93$ teams[A].conceded.away=1
```

Unfortunately, they do not autovivify from scratch, as hashes do in `perl`:

```
ksh93$ foo.bar.baz=quux
ksh93: foo.bar.baz=quux: no parent

ksh93$ foo=()  # or typeset -C foo
ksh93$ foo.bar.baz=quux

ksh93$ typeset -p foo
typeset -C foo=(bar=(baz=quux))
```